# How do I use an OAuth2 token with ANY version of the youtube python API

Tags: python, youtube, oauth-2.0

I'm grabbing an Oauth2 token with some functions I stripped out of:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Foauth2client

I tried:

```
yt_service              = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.developer_key    = YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY
yt_service.access_token     = FRESH_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
yt_service.client_id    = YOUTUBE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID
yt_service.email            = YOUTUBE_USER_EMAIL
yt_service.password         = YOUTUBE_USER_PASSWORD
yt_service.source           = YOUTUBE_DEV_SRC
yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
```

But I'm not sure how to properly get call `GetFormUploadToken` or `UpdateVideoEntry`. Previously I was just using a `developer_key` and it was working (using `gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()`).

I also tried using this example, but it isn't commented very well and the docs weren't any better:
https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/update_video.py

I tried simply changing
`build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))`

to

`build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    ACCESS_TOKEN=current_access_token)`

but it simply complains that it doesn't know what `ACCESS_TOKEN` is.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it.

```
def _yt_oauth_flow_hack(self, secret_json_str, scope, redirect_uri=None):
    """
    A hacked version of: oauth2client.clientflow_from_clientsecrets
    """
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loads(secret_json_str)
    if client_type in [clientsecrets.TYPE_WEB, clientsecrets.TYPE_INSTALLED]:
        return OAuth2WebServerFlow(
            client_info['client_id'],
            client_info['client_secret'],
            scope,
            redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
            user_agent=None,
            auth_uri=client_info['auth_uri'],
            token_uri=client_info['token_uri']
        )        
def begin_authentication(self):
    '''Starts the authentication process and returns the URL that we have to use to authorize the content
    if we need to authorize it, otherwise will generate the service and return None'''

    credentials = self._storage.get()
    if credentials is None:
        print 'Credentials Not Stored - We Require Fresh Authentication'
        flow = self._yt_oauth_flow_hack(AUTH_JSON, self.scope)
        flow.redirect_uri = OOB_CALLBACK_URN
        return flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    elif (credentials.invalid or credentials.token_expiry <= (datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=time.timezone))):
        print 'Credentials are Expired - Going to attempt to refresh them'
        try:
            http = httplib2.Http()
            credentials.refresh(http)
            print 'Success!'
        except AccessTokenRefreshError:
            print 'Unable to refresh credentials - requesting new ones.'
            flow = self._yt_oauth_flow_hack(AUTH_JSON, self.scope)
            flow.redirect_uri = OOB_CALLBACK_URN
            return flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

    print 'Credentials ->', credentials

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    self.service = build('youtube', 'v3', http=http)
    return None
```

The AUTH_JSON is what I downloaded when I setup my API account.  Storage is a customized version of their storage to work with a postgres db, but the principle is still the same.

Comment: That is just setting up the oauth2 credentials though, I already have a valid oauth2 token. I need to use the token to get a new upload URL and edit existing video metadata.

Comment: You do all of that through service.  Look at the last line before the return - you get your creds, authorize and then build.  Getting the creds authorized is the shitty part.

Comment: There's the notion of service accounts too, where you just use the data they give you to do stuff.  I can't get that to work using v3 and oAuth2 - the bindings and stuff are there but I spent a while with it and couldn't get it to do what I wanted.